# I want to develop basic level GameRanger link game lobby

Tags: c#, multiplayer, client-server, matchmaking

I want to develop basic level GameRanger link game lobby.

I am using Winform, C# Framework 4.0.
currently i am exploring below code
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14050/A-game-lobby-system-in-C?msg=5449482#xx5449482xx

But getting error to load gametypes/bridge.dll

desktop app GUI
[image]

Comment: Could you provide some more context: What programming language are you using? Could you briefly explain the functionality of a basic GameRanger link game lobby? Once your players connect to each other, what kind of data will they be communicating (e.g. position data, shared enemy data, "spells" or "bullets" data ... )? Are you looking to create a game lobby based on a "Friend List", or a lobby where players are automatically matches with each other based on experience level?

Comment: Currently i just want to create online server and host single multiplayer game for two known players

Comment: @Khurram so you want to create an intermediary/proxy to keep users in while waiting to have enough users to start a server?

Comment: Thanks for the edit! The error you mention could be caused by your application being unable to find the DLL file. A DLL is a library that is loaded at runtime (i.e. when your application is started, rather then when it was compiled). I would try to copy the DLL to the root directory of your application, or change the path in your code. A trick to find the root directory of your application is to quickly create a dummy file and store it as "./dummy_file.txt".